# Review on answer that fixes typo error by the OP

Tags: discussion, review-queues, scope

From what I understand questions that are based on a simple typographical error are considered as [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

With that as a fact, what is the optimal review for an answer to that question by the OP that resolves that error?

I can think of some scenarios:

- propose that the answer is an edit to the question since it is the OP that is resolving it AND it is an off-topic question.
- leave the answer as is

The first will delegate the problem to the evaluation of the question while the latest will leave a solid Question - Answer set for future reference.

Comment: Why does the answer even need to be reviewed?

Comment: So you prefer the second option

Comment: Definitely. You can still vote to close the question though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Do not suggest that the OP add their answer to the question!**

When the OP *answers* their question, their answer is an **answer** just like any other answer. It does not belong in the question. This is standard editorial practice on SO (and probably on any site of the SE network). If you encounter a question whose OP has edited in their answer, tell them to post their answer as an answer. (The fact that the question may eventually be closed as "off-topic" is no exception.)

When the answer amounts to "duh! I had this typo..." or any kind of "duh!..." I comment that the OP might want to delete their question because a) it does not add anything useful to SO, b) they may attract downvotes, c) 5 people will have to vote to close it and then more people will have to vote to delete it. (Going with the typical scenario where a diamond mod does not immediately intervene.)